# how to determine coordinates of my camera on first draw of an object openGL Es

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

I loaded a model from blender and I am trying to load it inside openGL but it shows a black window. My guess i that the camera is placed at a wrong spot and therefore I cannot see anything. The problem is that I dont know where to place my camera and set the projection matrice.

The code for my renderer:

```
public RocketArrowRenderer(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
        Resources res = mContext.getResources();
        InputStream inputStream = res.openRawResource(R.raw.rocket_obj);

        Obj obj = null;
        try {
            obj = ObjUtils.convertToRenderable(ObjReader.read(inputStream));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        IntBuffer indices = ObjData.getFaceVertexIndices(obj);
        mVertices = ObjData.getVertices(obj);
        //FloatBuffer texCoords = ObjData.getTexCoords(obj, 2);
        //FloatBuffer normals = ObjData.getNormals(obj);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);
        int vertexShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

        if (vertexShaderHandle != 0)
        {
            GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShaderHandle, vertexShader);
            GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShaderHandle);
            final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);
            if (compileStatus[0] == 0)
            {
                GLES20.glDeleteShader(vertexShaderHandle);
                vertexShaderHandle = 0;
            }

        }

        if (vertexShaderHandle == 0)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating vertex shader.");
        }

        // Load in the vertex shader.
        int fragmentShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        if(fragmentShader != null){
            GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShaderHandle, fragmentShader);
            GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShaderHandle);
            final int[] compileStatus2 = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus2, 0);
            if(compileStatus2[0] == 0){
                GLES20.glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderHandle);
                fragmentShaderHandle = 0;
            }
        }
        if(fragmentShader == null){
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating fragment shader");
        }
        int programHandle = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

        if (programHandle != 0)
        {
            GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, vertexShaderHandle);

            GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, fragmentShaderHandle);
            GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 0, "a_Position");
            GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 1, "a_Color");
            GLES20.glLinkProgram(programHandle);
            final int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetProgramiv(programHandle, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
            if (linkStatus[0] == 0)
            {
                GLES20.glDeleteProgram(programHandle);
                programHandle = 0;
            }
        }

        if (programHandle == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating program.");
        }
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_Position");
        GLES20.glUseProgram(programHandle);

    }
    private float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height)
    {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        final float ratio = (float) width / height;
        final float left = -ratio;
        final float right = ratio;
        final float bottom = -1.0f;
        final float top = 1.0f;
        final float near = 1.0f;
        final float far = 10.0f;

        Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused)
    {
        AsyncTask<RocketArrowRenderer, Void, Void> handle = new AsyncTask<RocketArrowRenderer, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(RocketArrowRenderer... renderers) {
                renderers[0].draw();
                return null;
            }

        };
        handle.execute(this);
    }


    public void draw() {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
        int numberOfTriangles = mVertices.position(0).remaining() / 3;
        mVertices.position(mPositionOffset);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, mPositionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                0, mPositionOffset);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        //and later, in draw
        GLES20.glUniform4f(mColorHandle, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); 
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numberOfTriangles);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show you code. How would we know what's *really* wrong without it? Could be a number of things.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog code is uploaded ..